# Android GCM Push notification not working

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-developers-console

I have recently created a new project on https://console.developers.google.com/. I got the sender-id and created API key. I integrated both on my app. But the notification is not working for some reason.

Also, I tried the push notification with my older project created on console and it works fine. So I think there is some problem with the new created project.

Any idea what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link it will work for you.
[Gcm_push_notification](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints)

First try to implement this 
 [GCM sample Quickstart app](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Actually I am using Titanium SDK cross platform technology.

I don't think there is any problem with the app as my older project(on google dev console) is working. But with the new project, the notification is not receiving.

I have enable the GCM api. Is there any other changes need to make?